# How do I show multiple items using bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

**I am trying to use carousel in my react project to show reviews.** I am using bootstrap carousel.
[This is the carousel I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whjGZ.jpg)

[But I want to use like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMXSU.jpg)

Every click on the button will slide in a item and one item will slide out.
I can do one at a time but not like this.

Here is my Code:

```
const ShowReviews = () => {
const { data: reviews, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery('reviews', () => fetch('https://.herokuapp.com/reviews',)
    .then(res => res.json()))
refetch()
if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading></Loading>
}
return (
    <div>
        <h1 className='text-center fw-bold my-5'>User Reviews ({reviews.length})</h1>
        <div className='bg-dark bg-opacity-25 container-fluid'>
            <Carousel>
                {reviews.map(review => <Carousel.Item> <ReviewCard
                    key={review._id}
                    review={review}
                ></ReviewCard></Carousel.Item>)}
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

export default ShowReviews;

Comment: Please always post code as text, not as image

Answer (score 0):

Just put three review cards per Carousel.Item instead of one. Carousel.Item is just a wrapper for one carousel "page".

*Carousel.Item* is already styled in a certain way, that's why you need a container/wrapper right below it. In my example I used *Stack* with direction="horizontal":

```
<Carousel.Item style={{ height: 500 }}>
  <Stack
    direction="horizontal"
    className="h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center"
    gap={3}
  >
    <Card>...</Card>
    <Card>...</Card>
    <Card>...</Card>
  </Stack>
</Carousel.Item>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-poitras-4w774i

Comment: it wont show me one by one like this site doing.. [link](https://drilled-74880.web.app/)
I just want to know as I don't find any sliderperview options as swiperJs is it possible with bootstrap.
Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: It's working - you just need an additional wrapper around the cards.

Comment: thanks man.. really appreciate your effort. This helps me a lot.